# Duplicate record issue on query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sample data

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE Cart (
    Id_cart INT NOT NULL,
    Id_product VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Id INT,
    Id_cart INT NOT NULL,
    Id_vendor INT NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(25),
  order_no VARCHAR(25)
);

-- data
INSERT INTO Cart
    (Id_cart, Id_product)
VALUES

    (1, 'abc002'),
    (1, 'abc003')
;
INSERT INTO Orders
    (Id, Id_cart,Id_vendor,status,order_no)
VALUES
    (1, 1,1, 'pending','aaa001'),
    (2, 1,2, 'pending','aaa002')
;
```

I use this query to show record.

```
Select c.id_cart,order_no,id_product from cart as c
left join  (SELECT id_cart,status,order_no FROM orders) o using(id_cart)
```

The result i get

```
id_cart     order_no    id_product
1           aaa002      abc002
1           aaa001      abc002
1           aaa002      abc003
1           aaa001      abc003
```

The result i expected

```
id_cart     order_no    id_product
1           aaa001      abc002
1           aaa002      abc003
```

Anything wrong with my query? How can i eliminate the duplicate record?

Let's say i added a column vendor_id to the orders table. Each order_no belong to one vendor and an id_cart will belong to many supplier. When i am trying to display my product, i want to display order_no and my id_product.

E.g. I have a cart belong to two order

1. an order belong to vendor A (1) and consist of product A and B.
2. an order belong to vendor B (2) and consist of product C and D.

During display the output should be

```
order_no | product_id
order1   | A
order1   | B
order2   | C
order2   | D
```

Now my problem is each order_no will be loop for each product_id. How can i overcome this?

Comment: There is no duplicate record. 1|aaa002|abc002 is different from 1|aaa002|abc003 as you can clearly see. What you are looking for is an aggregation per id_cart and order_no.

Comment: The id_cart is same for all records.

Comment: The `id_cart` appears in both tables.  A better design would be that the `cart` and `orders` table are connected via a junction table which relates carts to orders.  I think that `orders` itself should not know anything about carts.

Comment: What's the difference between a cart and an order of a given status?

Comment: Let's say if one cart will contain many product and each product will belong to their supplier. During purchase, i will separate the cart product into different order. The order will link to cart and a supplier, here i can know which product belong to which order_no.

Comment: You want 1|aaa002|abc002 in your results and 1|aaa002|abc003 not. Please explain what makes you decide so. Order aaa002 does contain product abc003, so what makes you want to dismiss this information?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I added Id_vendor. 1. Each id_cart may consist of many products from different vendor. 2. During creating order, i will assign an Id_vendor to the order_no created. 3. In my orders table, the id_cart might link to many vendor_id but each order_no only belong to one vendor. It uses to indicate Id_product belong to which Id_vendor and order_no consist of which Id_product.

Comment: I don't get it. If order aaa001 belongs to vendor X it still contains the two products abc002 and abc003. So by what rule shall we include order aaa001 with product abc002 in the results, but exclude abc003? What makes product abc002 important for order aaa001 and what makes product abc003 unimportant for it? Why do you want to show one and not the other?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Let's say for id_cart = 1, stored product A and product B. Then product A is belong to vendor A, while product B is belong to vendor B. In client side, when user click submit, it will separate the product into two order_no, where vendor A assign to order_no = 1 and vendor B assign to order_no = 2 .This is because there is vendor A and vendor B in one Cart. So when display, i want it to display  order_no =1 | product A , order_no = 2 | product B, instead of displaying order_no = 1 | product A and B, order_no = 2 | product A and B.

Comment: "Then product A is belong to vendor A": How do you know that? There seems to be nothing in your database to indicate this. There is no vendor_id in the cart table. Or is there a product table you haven't shown yet that contains the vendor_id?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, there is a product table which will link to vendor_id, vendor table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show cart products along with their orders. Carts contain products from different vendors for which exist separate orders. So join the product table to the cart in order to know the vendor and only then join the order table.

```
select
  id_cart,
  o.order_no,
  id_product 
from cart c
join product p using (id_product)
join orders o using (id_cart, id_vendor);
```

If you also want cart products for which no order has been written yet, make the orders join an outer join.

**UPDATE:** As you are reporting an issue with "Unknown column 'id_vendor' in 'from clause'", here is the query with ON clauses instead:

```
select
  c.id_cart,
  o.order_no,
  c.id_product 
from cart c
join product p on p.id_product = c.id_product
join orders o on o.id_cart = c.id_cart and o.id_vendor = p.id_vendor;
```

Comment: It shows error Unknown column 'id_vendor' in 'from clause'

Comment: But id_vendor exists in orders and products!? Well, I'll update my answer and replace the `USING` clauses with `ON` clauses. Maybe MySQL has issues with these.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple add [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to your sql Query

```
SELECT c.id_cart,order_no,id_product FROM cart AS c
left join  (SELECT id_cart,status,order_no FROM orders) o using(id_cart) GROUP BY o.order_no
```

**Example :-** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6b118/6/0

Comment: i have further explain what i actually need.

Comment: I don't like this answer at all. It still uses the unnecessary subquery (instead of simply using `left join orders o`), but most of all: this is an invalid query according to the SQL standard. MySQL lets this slip and returns arbitrarily picked `id_cart` and `id_product` per `order_no`. These don't even have to stem from the same record - the DBMS is free to choose any cart and any product linked to the order. I suggest you delete this answer or replace it with an answer elaborating the issue and containing a query returning id_cart and id_product from the same record.